# Error "no library trees found in 'lib.loc'" in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, install.packages

I'm trying to install ggplot2 in r and keep coming up with this error.
  I did the following commands,

```
install.packages("ggplot2", lib="/data/Rpackages/", dep=TRUE)  
library(ggplot2, lib.loc="/data/Rpackages/")
```

And it gives me the error:

> ```
> Error in library(ggplot2, lib.loc = "/data/Rpackages/") : 
>    no library trees found in 'lib.loc'
> ```

When I tried intalling it with just

```
install.packages("ggplot2",dep=TRUE)  
library(ggplot2)
```

And it gave me the error

> ```
> Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
> ```

I'm doing all of this in R studio on Debian.  Thanks

Comment: ggplot2 was not installed, so you get that error

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do that just by clicking on "Packages" and then to "Install" on the left of "Help" bottom?